# 聞いてもねえ事をペラペラと喋る。。。

Tags: translation

I can't understand the meaning of this sentence very well:
聞いてもねえ事をペラペラと喋る。。。

I know that 事をペラペラと喋る means to talk glibly about something, 聞いて comes from 聞く to listen, but I don't get the general meaning.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you understand it, when it's written as 聞いてもいない事をペラペラと喋る…?

Comment: Not really, I just know that 聞いてもいない is the negative form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part-by-part, it means

> 聞いてもいないこと things I haven't even asked
>   をペラペラと喋る talking glibly about

i.e. whoever is uttering this sentence is talking about a chatterbox, who talks about things nobody wants to hear (*lit.* about things nobody asked). A better translation might be

> 聞いてもねえ事をペラペラと喋る
>   He's just talking non-stop about things nobody's interested in (*lit.* about things I haven't even asked) .

There is a good chance that the speaker refers to someone, who talks a lot about himself/herself, his/her great achievements (i.e. to someone who expresses 自慢).

Answer (score -3):

ペラペラと喋る is to talk fluently about something as if one has a very good understanding of the topic.

聞いてもねえ事 means that he hasn't heard or asked about the topic, which implies that he doesn't have a good understanding of the topic.

The sentence is saying the subject appears to have a good understanding despite the speaker thinking that he shouldn't have a good understanding.

Comment: I don't think that is what it means. See my answer.